# Hibernate lazy initializaition error, why i got his?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Id", unique = true)
    private int id;


    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 5, max = 30)
    @Column(name = "Name")
    private String name;


    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Price")
    private double price;

    @ManyToMany( mappedBy = "products",fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Order> orders;
```

Many-to-many field is marked with LAZY fetch type.
But when i execute this simple code in my ProductDAO:

```
public List<Product> getProducts() {
    List<Product> products;
    String hql = "from Product";
    Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    products = session.createQuery(hql)
            .list();
    session.close();
    return products;
}
```

I get lazy initializaition error. I am new to the hibernate and i thought that i should get a Product object with empty collection, if fetch type is lazy. Where am I wrong?

Comment: what is the error message you are getting?

Comment: `Could not write content: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: org.training.ytaranau.model.Product.orders, could not initialize proxy - no Session`

Comment: Well, the orders are loaded lazily. But the session is closed, and the product is thus detached from the session, at the time you're iterating through the orders, so Hibernate has no way to lazily load the orders, hence the exception.

Comment: But I never tried to access orders, the only thing i do - return products as JSON: `@RequestMapping(value = "/products", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return productDao.getProducts();
    }`

Comment: The products need to be serialized to JSON. The JSON marshaller thus needs to serialize the orders of each product. So it lazily loads the orders. The stack trace of the exception should make that very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate `Lazy Fetch` Type will NOT load any entities (records) of relationships at the initial time.
Need `@Transaction` annotation for `Lazy Fetch` to associate relationship loaded entities with a Hibernate session. If NOT, an exception will be thrown.

You must implement with `@Transactional` for `Lazy Fetch` Type. That means you need to annotate your service method with `@Transactional` to use `LAZY` fetch. You have to configure transactions. Other solution is to switch back to `FetchType.EAGER`.